# Silverlight: convert UIElement to SVG

Tags: silverlight, svg, converters, uielement

I am looking for the best way of converting a `UIElement`(`FrameworkElement`) to vector format (vector analog for `WritableBitmap`).
The easiest way that comes to mind is manually create special SVG converter for some of `UIElement` implementations and try to get full vector image.

Generally it will be used for converting Canvases with Shapes.

Any ideas how to do this best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://sanpaku72.blogspot.com/2007/09/having-fun-with-xaml-silverlight-and.html

It has a link to http://members.chello.nl/~a.degreef/xaml/xaml2svg.xsl and download the other xsl files by following the includes, like http://members.chello.nl/~a.degreef/xaml/xaml2svg/animation.xsl

Comment: The question is how to convert full UI element, not only XAML part.